# Statistical Test to Identify Cause and Effect - Which is the best test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have the following data sample (I have much more data):

```
Language No. Of Articles    No. Of followers
Russian 100                 1000
English 80                  900
Korean  30                  525
```

I have the following assumptions to select from:

1-Language affects No. of followers,

2-Language and No. Of Articles affects No. Of followers.

3-No. of Articles affects No. of Followers. For this I can use the Correlation test.

What statistical test or measure do you suggest I use to identify which option is correct.

In short I want to know which factor(s) affect the number of followers?

Note: This is not a homework. I know little about Statistics!

Please help. Thx.

**Edit** - This is the graph of the tow variables (log/log):

[image]

Comment: Correlation measures, like Pearson, Kendall, Spearman coefficents.

Comment: To add to what @Kodiologist said, inferring causality from non-experimental (observational) data is possible only under certain strong assumptions. See the work by Judea Pearl  here: http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/home.htm

Comment: @Ganu, I took a look at the 3-part presentation, but my question under Kodiologist's answer is not yet answered. Why would using a correlation be wrong? I understand that we can't be sure that if given A, then B will occur (as demonstrated by Smoking and Cancer in the above paper), however,  sometimes we have to work with the data we have and place appropriate remarks on the results. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You have neither experimental nor longitudinal data. Hence, you have nothing with which to identify any causal relationships.

Comment: Could you please explain more, or provide a link - I am not a statistician. I though that at least for #3, calculating correlation would be meaning full - Why not? Thanks.

Comment: RationalWiki has [a nice informal description](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) of the problem of inferring causation from correlation. Note that the same arguments apply to any kind of association, not just correlation.